# Php string condition check for plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wpallimport

I have that function inside on a wp all import plugin for Wordpress to import products,that takes the first value and renames to the second value, a simple mapping function.

I want simply insert an condition that checking that strings and if isn't on that strings then the new string will be $cat=uncategorized>$cat in other words if isnt on my dictionary for example
$cat=cars then i want to replace to uncategorized>cars

```
function cat_change($cat){
    
    $cat = str_replace("XLARGE", "XL", $cat);
    $cat = str_replace("xl", "XL", $cat);
    $cat = str_replace("extralarge", "XL", $cat);
    
    
    $cat = str_replace("XXL", "2XL", $cat);
    $cat = str_replace("2XLARGE", "2XL", $cat);
    $cat = str_replace("2large", "2XL", $cat);
    $cat = str_replace("2xlarge", "2XL", $cat);
    
    $cat = str_replace("XXXL", "3XL", $cat);
    $cat = str_replace("3XLARGE", "3XL", $cat);
    $cat = str_replace("3large", "3XL", $cat);
    $cat = str_replace("3xlarge", "3XL", $cat);


    return $cat;
}
```

Comment: So what is `$size` and where can it be found. Should that be `$cat`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sry i renamed, was my fault on paste code, that function working, but i want check , if isnt on that strings then , return something else...
maybe must go with for? please give me an example

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking. Are you saying if non if the words you are looking for are in the string `$cat` then do some other string should be returned from the function

Comment: @RiggsFolly Exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can pass arrays to `str_replace` so all those lines can be done in one.

You can then use the `$find` array and `explode()` to search using `in_array()` to check at least one of the words in `$find` exists in the `$cat` string

```
function cat_change($cat){
    $find = ['XLARGE', 'xl','extralarge', 'XXL', '2XLARGE', '2large', '2xlarge', 'XXXL', '3XLARGE', '3large', '3xlarge'];
    $replace = ['XL','XL','XL', '2XL', '2XL','2XL','2XL','3XL','3XL','3XL','3XL'];

    $allwords = explode(' ', $cat);
    $found = FALSE;
    foreach ($find as $word){
        if (in_array($word, $allwords)){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found){
        return 'something else';
    }
    $cat = str_replace($find, $replace, $cat);
    return $cat;
}

$input = 'The quick XLARGE fox jumped over the 2XLARGE moon';
echo $input . PHP_EOL;
echo cat_change($input);
```

RESULT

```
The quick XLARGE fox jumped over the 2XLARGE moon
The quick XL fox jumped over the 2XL moon
```

Or using input that does no have any find value in it

```
$input = 'The quick fox jumped over the moon';
echo $input . PHP_EOL;
echo cat_change($input);
```

RESULTS IN

```
The quick fox jumped over the moon
something else
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, One more think the categories that im taking from xml is like this
 <categories>bags>1|bags>2
</categories>
the | is the separator of the second data and the > is the subcategory hierarchy 

I change the explode to  explode('|', $cat); and make true one of the two categories, i inserted that bags>1|bags>2 so checked  that bags>1 is true and correctly renamed to womens>bags>1 , 
but they continue also to the bags>2 , isnt correct must return:

womens>bags>1 
'something else'

   $find = ['bags>1','xxl'];
   $replace = ['womens>bags>1','2xl'];